# Why is my SharePoint 2013 site collection and developer site not letting the site administrator access it?

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an on-premises SharePoint 2013 server running on Windows Server 2012 R2, with all updates installed and everything configured. The central admin works fine with no issues. However, the site collection and the developer site both do not allow access from both the domain administrator and the site collection administrator. Both are given access to both sites, and I've tried several steps to resolve the issue, including playing with authentication methods (I'd like to use basic authentication with SSL) but nothing seems to fix the issue.

I've noticed the issue started around when I was trying to set up a service on the SP server, but I cannot remember which service it was, or how I did its set up.

How can I grant access to my site and domain admins to the collection and the developer site? Thanks.

P.S. a side note, it just seems to relate to the home page of both sites, as I can access the site settings page and the documents pages as well.